# current location information from network provider

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, blackberry-simulator

In my appliaction iwant to know the current loction in 2 ways 1) GPS based and 2) network based(using network provider's towers),
I found solution for the first one.
How can I do the 2nd method.I stucked here.Can any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same API for both, just different criteria on how to get the fix. This is all described in the [BlackBerry Location-Based Services Development Guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17954/index.jsp?name=Location-Based+Services+-+Development+Guide+-+BlackBerry+Java+SDK6.0&language=English&userType=21&category=Development+Guides&subCategory=).